# a question about calculus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

is calculus about finding the rate of change  of a function ? or are we trying to find the Slope ( Gradient ) of a Curve ??

are differential calculus and differential equation the same thing ??

Comment: These questions seem too general, maybe consult a summary of calculus...

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus):

> **Calculus is the mathematical study of change**, in the same way that geometry is the study of shape and algebra is the study of operations and their application to solving equations. It has two major branches, **differential calculus** (concerning rates of change and slopes of curves), and **integral calculus** (concerning accumulation of quantities and the areas under and between curves); these two branches are related to each other by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Differential calculus and differential equation are not the same thing, but related. Differential calculus deals with the study of basically everything concerning [derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative), and differential equations are one of those things. So one could say that the study of differential equations is a subfield of differential calculus.